# Resize root Partition that is lvm'ed

Tags: server, partitioning, gparted, lvm, boot-partition

I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I have a partition that is lvm'ed and I'm trying to increase it's size. This is on a VM machine, I first started with a 40G and increased it to a 100GB HD. I have full access to machine.

What I have done so far, booted with ubuntu desktop and used the following application: Gparted, kvpm and kde partition manager. (I've included a snapshot from gparted)[image]

All the application that I used state they cannot extend the size of /dev/sda5.

- Gparted:drives are locked
- kvpm:no options, all options are greyed out
- kde parition manager:gives me the option to extend /dev/sda2, but fails when it tries

I tried booting using rescue disk and booted to a shell. I used the resize2fs command without luck.[image]

I'm out of ideas other than reinstall. I don't want to create a 60G partition and mount it to the root partition.

Comment: Boot from an Ubuntu live USB/CD (i.e. boot as if you're reinstalling Ubuntu, but choose "Try Ubuntu"). Open GParted, right click sda5, choose Unmount if it's mounted, right click sda2, resize it to take up the empty 60GB space, then resize sda5 to take up the new empty space that'll be inside sda2. Apply changes, boot back into your Ubuntu.

Comment: Well that worked.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Alaa Ali, I was able to figure out a solution.

1. Boot with Ubuntu Desktop (USB/CD)
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu"
3. Start GParted
4. Right Click on the lvm partition and select deactivate.
5. Right Click on the extended partition and select resize/move
6. Resize the partition
7. Right Click on the lvm partition and select activate.
8. Right Click on the lvm partition and select resize/move
9. Resize the partition
10. Apply the changes
11. Reboot